# Webform Submission not Working with .tpl.php file

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I have a webform that i needed to style a little differently. So I did this creating a `webform-form-3.tpl.php` file (the node of my form is 3). Inside that I have this code:

```
<?php // Contact Us form ?>
<div id="left-column">
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['event']);?>
</div>
<div id="right-column">
    <div class="form-actions">
        <?php print drupal_render($form['actions']['submit']);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, by doing this, it stops the submitting functionality of the form. I am assuming that I messed up on missing some of the submitting options. Does anyone have any ideas where i may have gone wrong? Any help would me much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick this at the bottom:

```
<?php echo drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```